# move a large div opposite to mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table full of data that tends to be larger than the screen.

I put the table in a DIV and set the "overflow" to "auto" in CSS

```
div.scrolling-comps {
    width : 970px;
    height : 800px;
    overflow : auto;
}
```

So the DIV can be scrolled up/down, left right using the browser's built-in scroll bars.

Problem is, the table can be WAAY bigger than the screen. And while the mousewheel will scroll it up/down, scrolling left/right is a pain in the hooch.

So, looking for a javascript/jquery or CSS way to scroll the div ***NATURALLY***.

In other words, when someone viewing the huuuge table moves their mouse to the right, the DIV goes to the left (thus scrolling without using the scroll bars).

Something similar to this, but instead of *following the mouse*, the div would move *opposite the mouse*...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bsDiv = document.getElementById("box-shadow-div");
  var x, y;
  // On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
      bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
      bsDiv.style.top = y + "px";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
#box-shadow-div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black;
  top: 49%;
  left: 48.85%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-shadow-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you have about using the mouse position is interesting... But it is not what you need to achieve what you described.

In fact... What you need to know is the "ratio" between the `div` wrapping the `table` and its [`scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth)

Then, using the `X` position of the mouse, you can apply a scroll to the `div` in order to make it "move".

I used jQuery to do it using very few lines.

```js
// Just to fake a big table
var fakeCell = $("<td>Some data</td>");
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
  var fakeRow = $("<tr>");
  for(k=0;k<50;k++){
    fakeRow.append(fakeCell.clone().append(" "+k));
  }
  $("#test").append(fakeRow.clone());
}
// ---------------------------------------------------


// Calculate the "ratio" of the box-div width versus its scrollable width
var ratio = $("#box-div")[0].scrollWidth / $("#box-div").width();
console.log("Ratio: "+ratio);

// Scroll left/rigth based on mouse movement
$(window).on("mousemove", function(e){
  var X = ratio * e.pageX;
  
  // Scroll the div using the mouse position multiplyed by the ratio
  $("#box-div").scrollLeft(X);
});
```

```css
td{
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#box-div{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="box-div">
    <table id="test">
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

So while the user moves the mouse over the div's width, you apply a scroll multiplied by the ratio... The effect is the user can scroll it all from the most left to most right ends easilly.

Comment: Yea, that's looking good. The scroll is horizontal only, but mousewheel can scroll the the table vertically.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

wrap a table in div (i.e. parent-div) which is relatively positioned

Give position `absolute` to the target div.

And change left & top position of target div on `mousemove` event.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bsDiv = document.getElementById("box-shadow-div");
  var x, y;
  // On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
      bsDiv.style.left = -x + "px";
      bsDiv.style.top = -y + "px";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.parent-div {
    position: relative;
}
#box-shadow-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
    <div id="box-shadow-div"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing x to -x? this will technically "invert" the effect.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bsDiv = document.getElementById("box-shadow-div");
  var x, y;
  // On mousemove use event.clientX and event.clientY to set the location of the div to the location of the cursor:
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
      bsDiv.style.left = -x + "px";
      bsDiv.style.top = -y + "px";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
#box-shadow-div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black;
  top: 49%;
  left: 48.85%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-shadow-div"></div>
```